Filament V3 belongstomany with pivot attribute to fill
First I am using filament form builder not panel.
My question:
I have a ManyToMany relationship in filament, and when I save the form everything works very well, the main model and these relations saved perfectly, but I need to fill some value in pivot table because the child was selected in base these columns value in pivot table.
schema of relationship
When I create Famille entity with Personne as relationships, it will create perfectly but without Categorie id, how can I specify the pivot attribute?

You could use a Filament Repeater inside your form, but that means you also need to create a pivot model to manage your model relationships.
If you want to do it this way:
Step 1
Create the PersonneFamilie pivot model:
// app/Models/PersonneFamille.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class PersonneFamille extends Pivot
{

    protected $table = 'personne_famille';

    public function famille(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Famille::class);
    }

    public function personne(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Personne::class);
    }

    public function categorie(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categorie::class);
    }
}

Step 2
Update the involved models (replace the relation functions in each of the 3 models to be able to access the relationship from the models):
//rename the function it if needed
public function personneFamille()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PersonneFamille::class);
}

Step 3
Add the repeater field in the form. If the form is inside Famille resource, add the two other fields from the pivot table:
//FamilleResource.php

//use Filament\Forms\Components\Repeater;
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Repeater::make('personneFamille') //the function name from step 2
                    ->relationship()
                    ->schema([
                        Select::make('personne_id')
                            ->relationship('personne', 'name') //replace 'name' with your desired column
                            ->required(),
                        Select::make('categorie_id')
                            ->relationship('categorie', 'name') //replace 'name' with your desired column
                            ->required(),
                    ])
                    ->columns(2), //optional
                    // ...

Pivot table source from: Laravel documentation
Repeater field source from: Filament documentation

thanks Clain very match , if i understand , i must use belongsTo instead of belongstomany , becose in this way i can edit the pivot table and fill it manualy by form. i will try this solution step by step and i will cam back to you , thanks a gain

This is one way of doing it, could be others. If you need any clarifications let me know.
